# How to merge two divs and put header on every roww in a table

Tags: html, css

I'm creating the layout for a web application, but I want the right and left containers to be unified. I do not know how I can merge these two divs. Please help me.

And I want to add column head in every row but I do not know how to do it. I statically add rows with jQuery.

This is my code:

```
<div class="row" >
   <div class="col-md-8" >

      <table class="table table-striped" id="our_table"  >

         <tr >
            <th >Vehicle
                           </th >
            <th >Type
                           </th >
            <th >Date
                          </th >
            <th >Route</th>


         </tr >

         <tr ng-repeat="person in filteredPersons = (persons | filter:sensitiveSearch | orderBy:order)"
             ng-style="{
                   'background-color': $index == selectedIndex ? '#E9CF30' : ''
               }"
             ng-click="selectPerson(person, $index)" >
            <td >{{ person.vehicle }}</td >
            <td >{{ person.type }}</td >
            <td >{{ person.date  }}</td >
            <td >{{ person.route  }}</td >
         </tr >
         <tr ng-show="filteredPersons.length == 0">
            <td colspan="4">
               <div class="alert alert-info">
                  <p class="text-center">No results found for search term '{{ search }}'</p>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>


      </table >

   </div >
   <div class="col-md-4 p-0 " >

      <div class="panel panel-default"  >
         <div class="panel-heading" ></div >
         <div class="panel-body" >

            <dl >
               <dt >Captain</dt >
               <dd >{{selectedPerson.captain}}</dd >

               <dt >Operation</dt >
               <dd >{{selectedPerson.operation}}</dd >

               <dt >Type(s)</dt >
               <dd >{{selectedPerson.type}}</dd >



            </dl >
            <div class="dropdown" >
               <button
                     style="width: 100%;font-family: 'Open Sans';
                       font-size: 19px;
                       font-weight: bold;
                       color: #172C49;"
                     class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-md" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">TAKE ACTION
                  <span class="caret"></span></button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">MARK AS SEEN</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">CREATE AN AD-HOC TASK</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">MAKE A COMMENT</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
               <img class="img-responsive" id="myImg" src="picture.png" alt="Picture">
```

For a clearer understanding: [frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTKSq.png)

And this is what I want: [frontend 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLeFW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap v4 you can add a `no-gutters` class on the row, if not you can add a new class to remove the default padding from columns like this:

```
.padding-0{
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
}
```

In version 3.4 you also have a class you can add to the row called `row-no-gutters`

Comment: Thank you it is work! Can you help me in other problem? As you can see in second image link, table has column header in every row. But I cannot do it? How can I do it? Any idea?

Comment: You can create a div as a direct child of the table element, then you can loop over the data in that div element instead of just in one of the table rows.